# Get domain from strange yet valid url with java

Tags: java, url

I need to get host from this url

```
android-app://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox?Pub_id={siteID}
```

`java.net.URL` and `java.net.URI` can't handle it.

Comment: If there is no protocol handler installed for `android-app:` then one would receive an exception with "unknown protocol". Also `{}` might be problemation: `"...?Pub_id=" + URLEncoder.encode("{siteID}", "UTF-8"):` Though I suspect you need to fill in `{siteId}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in `{` and `}` characters which are not valid for URI. Looks like a placeholder that wasn't resolved correctly when creating a URI.

You can use `String.replaceAll()` to get rid of these two characters:

```
String value = "android-app://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox?Pub_id={siteID}";
URI uri = URI.create(value.replaceAll("[{}]", ""));
System.out.println(uri.getHost()); // com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
```

Comment: Could you please write all characters which are not valid for URI. I know another one "\"

Comment: @DennisGlot see https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/

Answer (score 1):

You see, eventually I need path, scheme and query.
I've just found super fast library for parsing such URLs. https://github.com/anthonynsimon/jurl
It's also very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
String url = "android-app://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox?Pub_id={siteID}";
        url = url.replace("{", "").replace("}","");
        URI u;
        try {
            u = new URI(url);
            System.out.println(u.getHost());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```